# python google colab directory access error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, google-colaboratory

I am working with google colab. I am facing slow access rate to my image directory from colab to drive. After some investigation, I saw to improve to the rate, you have to copy the zip from drive to colab and unzip into colab. My issue is when I perform `process_images` function it returns me an error: `error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'`.

However if I do `ls` on the directory I have the files in the colab directory. Note this error doesn't not appear when I access from google drive.

I copy the zip from google drive to colab

```
!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/invasive_60000.zip /content/invasive/
```

I unzip the archive in the colab directory

```
!unzip -q /content/invasive/invasive_60000.zip
```

I check if files are there:

```
!ls -la /content/invasive_60000/
```

I define my image patches: `imagePatches = glob('/content/invasive_60000', recursive=True)`

define my function process image:

```
def process_images(lowerIndex,upperIndex):
    """
    Returns two arrays: 
        x is an array of resized images
        y is an array of labels
    """ 
    height = 50
    width = 50
    channels = 3
    x = [] #list to store image data
    y = [] #list to store corresponding class
    for img in imagePatches[lowerIndex:upperIndex]:
        full_size_image = cv2.imread(img)
        image = (cv2.resize(full_size_image, (width,height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
        x.append(image)
        if img in classZero:
            y.append(0)
        elif img in classOne:
            y.append(1)
        else:
            return
    return x,y
```

When I call the function: `X, Y = process_images(0,60000)` I have this error:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-8fa6697d3af2> in <module>()
----> 1 X, Y = process_images(0,60000) #it has to be 60000

<ipython-input-21-129e46598d2e> in process_images(lowerIndex, upperIndex)
     12     for img in imagePatches[lowerIndex:upperIndex]:
     13         full_size_image = cv2.imread(img)
---> 14         image = (cv2.resize(full_size_image, (width,height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
     15         x.append(image)
     16         if img in classZero:

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

It is like the folder is empty of images. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I understood my error, `imagePatches = glob('/content/invasive_60000/**/*.png', recursive=True)` as to be written like that recursively on all pictures.